# Check for up Sonar on my project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, sonarqube

in the project that I am, we are evaluating SONAR test for the system, I downloaded the Sonar Eclipse plugin, I have stated in my Maven.
Finally I downloaded the 3.7 Sonar small server.

sonar-3.7\bin\windows-x86-64

When I run the StartSonar.bat
I get this error on the console:

```
STATUS | wrapper  | 2013/11/14 10:26:55 | --> Wrapper Started as Console
STATUS | wrapper  | 2013/11/14 10:26:55 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/11/14 10:26:56 | Unrecognized VM option '+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError'
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/11/14 10:26:56 | Could not create the Java virtual machine.
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2013/11/14 10:26:56 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2013/11/14 10:27:00 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2013/11/14 10:27:00 | Unrecognized VM option '+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError'
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2013/11/14 10:27:00 | Could not create the Java virtual machine.
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2013/11/14 10:27:00 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2013/11/14 10:27:04 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2013/11/14 10:27:04 | Unrecognized VM option '+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError'
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2013/11/14 10:27:04 | Could not create the Java virtual machine.
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2013/11/14 10:27:04 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2013/11/14 10:27:08 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2013/11/14 10:27:08 | Unrecognized VM option '+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError'
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2013/11/14 10:27:08 | Could not create the Java virtual machine.
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2013/11/14 10:27:08 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2013/11/14 10:27:13 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 5    | 2013/11/14 10:27:13 | Unrecognized VM option '+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError'
INFO   | jvm 5    | 2013/11/14 10:27:13 | Could not create the Java virtual machine.
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2013/11/14 10:27:13 | JVM exited while loading the application.
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2013/11/14 10:27:13 | There were 5 failed launches in a row, each lasting less than 300 seconds.  Giving up.
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2013/11/14 10:27:13 |   There may be a configuration problem: please check the logs.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2013/11/14 10:27:13 | <-- Wrapper Stopped
```

Someone could advise me on this problem, please.

Comment: Have you solved this problem ? please help

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed the JDK on the same pc/server? Is JAVA_HOME declared in your environment variables and added in the PATH ?

And what about sonar-3.7\conf\wrapper.conf? You have to find there something like

```
wrapper.java.command=java
```

or

```
wrapper.java.command=%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java
```